# Can a Thief use a Trick without moving?

Tags: dnd-4e, thief

Can a Thief use a Trick power to gain a benefit without actually moving? For example, could they use Thug's Trick to make shifting provoke OAs or Acrobat's Trick to gain a damage bonus without shifting/moving (respectively)?

If so, would Acrobat's Trick still provoke an OA from adjacent enemies?

Comment: +1, Good couple of questions so far. Obviously it's not a big deal, as you already have a good answer, but I would have found this a lot easier to answer with either some of the rules text from the abilities you're asking about or a reference to the source: "Thug's Trick, from Martial Power 2" or wherever it's from. Just a tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The abilities simply allow you to move or shift "up to" a certain number of squares, and 0 is an allowable number. The fact that they are a Move Action is irrelevant.

This is the same wording used on Forced Movement (**Compendium, Forced Movement**):

> When a distance is specified, it is a maximum; the creature or effect producing the forced movement can move its target up to that number of squares (or none at all). For instance, a character's power might say, "You slide the target 4 squares (or up to 4 squares)"; both mean the character can move the target up to 4 squares or not move it at all.

As for *Acrobat's Trick*, it will not provoke an *Opportunity Attack* because you never leave the square you are in. See the **Compendium, Opportunity Attack**:

> Moving Provokes: If an enemy leaves a square adjacent to you, you can make an opportunity attack against that enemy.